# s3_direct_upload as a rake task gives url is invalid - how do I set direct_upload_url directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using s3_direct_upload with PaperClip through the web UI, this is all working perfectly.

However, I have a rake task that is looking for files to upload in the background and using the same process to load in the jobs, this is currently giving an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Direct upload url can't be blank, Direct upload url is invalid
```

This is not unexpected, as the background task is not using the javascript tools to upload the file.

How do I set the correct direct_upload_url so the existing processing can continue?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that works is to basically duplicate what has been done for the direct upload (as an indirect upload) and make them conditional. Once I thought through exactly what the code was doing it became more obvious.

Only fiddly part was the pattern matching for the direct_upload_url which will be somewhat dependant on your situation

below are the relvant parts of my model that were changed to deal with either situation

```
  BUCKET_NAME         = ENV['AWS_BUCKET'] 
  UPLOAD_BUCKET_NAME  = ENV['UPLOAD_BUCKET']
  DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT = %r{\Ahttps:\/\/#{BUCKET_NAME}\.s3\.amazonaws\.com\/(?<path>uploads\/.+\/(?<filename>.+))\z}.freeze
  INDIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT = %r{\Ahttps:\/\/#{UPLOAD_BUCKET_NAME}\.s3\.amazonaws\.com\/(?<filename>.+)\z}.freeze

  validates :direct_upload_url, presence: true, format: { with: DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT }, if: :direct_upload?
  validates :direct_upload_url, presence: true, format: { with: INDIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT }, if: :indirect_upload?

  # attributes have already been set - file is already up on S3 
  before_create :set_upload_attributes, if: :direct_upload?
  after_create :queue_finalize_and_cleanup

...

  def self.finalize_and_cleanup(id)
    import = Import.find(id)
    if import.indirect_upload?
      direct_upload_url_data = INDIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT.match(import.direct_upload_url)
    else
      direct_upload_url_data = DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT.match(import.direct_upload_url)
    end
    s3 = AWS::S3.new
    if import.post_process_required?
      import.import_file = URI.parse(URI.escape(import.direct_upload_url))
    else
      paperclip_file_path = "imports/import_files/#{id}/original/#{direct_upload_url_data[:filename]}"
      if import.indirect_upload?
        # coming from a different bucket, and there is no PATH variable 
        s3.buckets[BUCKET_NAME].objects[paperclip_file_path].copy_from(direct_upload_url_data[:filename], { bucket_name: UPLOAD_BUCKET_NAME })
      else
        s3.buckets[BUCKET_NAME].objects[paperclip_file_path].copy_from(direct_upload_url_data[:path])
      end
    end

    import.processed = true
    import.state = 'Queued'
    import.save
    import.process

    if import.indirect_upload?
      s3.buckets[UPLOAD_BUCKET_NAME].objects[direct_upload_url_data[:filename]].delete
    else
      s3.buckets[BUCKET_NAME].objects[direct_upload_url_data[:path]].delete
    end

  end
```